# Generate PDFs in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

How does one generate and read PDF files in Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CGPDFDocument](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) and the related classes; see the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) for an overview.

Comment: Thanks smorgan, ill look in to this.