# Programmatically call "Save to PDF..." Sheet

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, pdf, printing

I need to implement a feature that under a certain condition the "Save to PDF" Dialog shows up & the user can save their document to PDF. How is this achieved in Objective C, C or C++ i.e in Mac OS X? (anyone of them is good).

Comment: What are "certain conditions"?

Comment: I have a program that maps printers of a client computer onto the server (connected by RDP), if the users selects Microsoft's XPS client from a mac I want to show a dialog saying it is not supported & give the option to print as PDF instead

Comment: possible duplicate: [Generate PDF in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252810/generate-pdf-in-objective-c), [among](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+create+pdf) [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+generate+pdf)

Comment: Technically I don't want to create a PDF myself I just want to call the Save As PDF Dialog and let the system do all the work

Answer (score 1):

In textedit, there's an option to save as PDF.  So you might be able to find how to do it in the textedit source provided by apple.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to write a file which conforms to [the PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) from Adobe.  (Now also an ISO Standard).   [Apple provides an API here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101)